# AspectJ in Gradle - Intellij Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

For a whole day i've been trying to use AspectJ - adding dependencies, installing plugins, creating .aj files or marking with @Aspect annotation, but nothing seems to work on gradle. Please help me to understand my problem.

My GreetingAspect.aj file

```
package org.example;

public aspect GreetingAspect {

    pointcut greeting() : execution(* Main.printName(..));

    before() : greeting() {
        System.out.print("Hello ");
    }
}
```

The code should print "Hello (name)" before every instance of .printName(), so i can see that "poincut" and "before" is working

1. My build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "8.3"
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'

    runtimeOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7'
    runtimeOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.7'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.7'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

3. Main

```
package org.example;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printName("Max");
        printName("John");
        printName("Martin");
    }

    public static void printName(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

I tried to:
Install AspectJ plugin from market, that added support for .aj, but they seem to do nothing at all,
install AspectJ plugins from https://plugins.gradle.org/,
Installing .jar directly in lib,
Changing version from 1.9.10 to 1.9.7,
instead of .aj using .java classes but with @Aspect annotation.

Comment: Don't post images of code ([reasons here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)). Ensure everything necessary to understand the problem is included as text directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have both source files in *src/main/java* or only the aspect in *src/main/aspectj*, but in the default configuration, Freefair expects all source files to reside in *src/main/aspectj*:

[image: Gradle project directory layout for Freefair AspectJ]

Then, the project works flawlessly.

---

**[Optional]** You can, however, also streamline your Gradle build config a little bit and also update AspectJ to a more recent version, because 1.9.7 only supports Java 16, but 1.9.20 supports up to Java 20.

```java
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "8.3"
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
  implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.20'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

**Update 2023-10-10:** Freefair 8.4 now defaults to `src/main/java`, i.e. it works as expected with a standard directory layout, just like with AspectJ Maven.

Comment: See here for an example on how to use src/main/java instead of src/main/aspectj https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0c714e3a7808199cb7e8b128026f7b0cae39e5de/spring-aspects/spring-aspects.gradle#L5-L9

Comment: @larsgrefer, thanks for the helpful hint. However, I cannot help but wonder why the default requires a custom directory at all. AspectJ Maven Plugin, for example, does not, it just works with a standard Maven directory layout. This is utterly counter-intuitive and not documented in [Freefair's plugin documentation](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.3/reference/#_aspectj) at all. I would not have looked for an example in Spring's source code.

Comment: It works analog to the existing gradle plugins for Groovy, Scala and Kotlin which put their sources in `src/main/groovy`, `src/main/scala` and `src/main/kotlin` respectively. So each compiler gets its own directory. `src/main/java` is always* compiled by javac, `src/main/aspectj` is always compiled by ajc and so on.

The default source folder is documented right here: https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.3/reference/#_io_freefair_aspectj

Comment: Thanks for updating the documentation.  Concerning the question of the default directory, I created [issue 881](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/881) in your project.

Comment: **Update:** Freefair 8.4 now defaults to `src/main/java`, i.e. it works as expected with a standard directory layout, just like with AspectJ Maven.